# Color in button only showing on half of button

Tags: html, css, asp.net, button

I'm trying to create a button but the style isn't displaying right. I'm trying to set the colour to blue but it is only showing on half of the button:

[image]

Code for the button:

```
<asp:Button CssClass="button" ID="btnLogin2" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
```

CSS Code:

```
<style>
        .button {
          padding: 10px 20px;
          font-size: 20px;
          text-align: center;
          cursor: pointer;
          outline: none;
          color: #fff;
          background-color: #4db8ff;
          border: none;
          border-radius: 15px;
          box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
        }

        .button:hover {background-color: #1aa3ff}

        .button:active {
          background-color: #1aa3ff;
          box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
          transform: translateY(4px);
        }
</style>
```

The button styles work fine if I don't use `asp:Button` 
i.e. `<button class="button">Log in</button>` looks like this:

[image]

How do I get the style to work on the asp button?

Comment: Can you please try updating the class name?

Comment: It would be worth inspecting the resultant html element on browser for both case i.e. `asp:Button` and `button`

Comment: I quickly checked in a clean project and it works fine. There is probably  other css interfering. Try background-color: #4db8ff !important;

Comment: Use the developer tools in your browser to inspect the element.

Comment: A button in aspnet becomes `<input type=button>`, not `<button>`. I'm guessing @H.Mikhaeljan is right and another css is interfering.